# Search error in last 24 hours in log files

Tags: linux

I want to find oracle error that happend in last 24 hours in listener.log file. How can i do it in linux that will print out the timestamp as well . Please help

Comment: A few lines of example output would be helpful. Not everyone who is able to help you will have a logfile ready to use. 
But generally speaking: in linux tools like grep, awk and sed are your friends.

Comment: Sorry buddy. Here i tried to built but it does not work.

Comment: awk -v d="$(date -d'24 hours ago' +'%F %T,000')" '$1" "$2>=d &&/TNS-/' listener/log

Comment: awk -v d="$(date -d'24 hours ago' +'%F %T,000')" '$1" "$2>=d &&/TNS-/' listener.log

Answer (score 0):

i have log file with below format.

> 13-SEP-2016 22:09:00 INFO  ${logging message go here.}

```
sed -n -e '/^13-SEP-2016 22:09:00/,/^15-SEP-2016 23:09:01/p' listener.log
```

above command will filter log with specified time duration then use `grep` command to filter oracle error..
you can try this by changing time duration as per your requirement.

Comment: You don't need `grep`. Just `sed '/2017-02-22 18:29:30/,/2017-02-22 18:29:31/{/PATTERN/p}' `

Comment: Shows nothing.PLSDE40:/orahome/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/PLSDE40/listener/trace # sed -n '/22-FEB-2017 18:29:30/,/22-FEB-2017 18:29:31/p' listener.log
PLSDE40:/orahome/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/PLSDE40/listener/trace #

Comment: Sorry this is the one

Comment: sed -n '/21-FEB-2017 15:00:00/,/21-FEB-2017 19:00:00/p' listener.log shows nothing

Comment: @user3297431 can you please try with below command 
sed -n -e '/^13-SEP-2016 22:09:00/,/^15-SEP-2016 23:09:01/p' listener.log